# How to add test to Manually Registering Events Listener in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-7

I have a manually registering event and related listener. For this i want to add test so i checked laravel `Mocking Test` in documentation but i didn't find any way to test **manually registering event with parameter listener**. So anyone help me how to do this? Below i attached working related code.

Event is calling in the `TeamObserver deleting` method like below

```
class TeamObserver
{
    public function deleting(Team $team)
    {
    event('event.team.deleting', array('team' => $team));
    }
}
```

Event and Listeners are registered in `EventServiceProvider boot` method like below

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    Event::listen(
        'event.team.deleting',
        'Listeners\TeamDeletingListener'
    );
}
```

`TeamDeletingListener` is look like below

```
class TeamDeletingListener
{
    public function handle($team)
    {
        \Log::info('Deleting Inventory Module');
        \Log::info($team);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Any Genies????

Comment: Do you want to "unit" test? If yes which method do you want to ? If it is integration or feature, from where to where you want to test ?

Comment: Yes i want to test unit test feature. From Observer deleting event to listener. Mainly i want to test i receive correct value. For example from above `$team`.

Comment: Did my answer help you, @Dev ? If not, could you tell me what's missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this, is to replace the real implementation of your listener with a mocked one. Here's an example test. It will fail if you remove `event('event.team.deleting', array('team' => $team));` or pass a different team. If I got you right, that's what you want to achieve.

```
public function testTeamDeletion()
{
    // Persist team that should be deleted
    $team       = new Team();
    $team->name = 'My Team';
    $team->save();

    // Mock the listener
    $this->mock(
        TeamDeletingListener::class,
        function (MockInterface $mock) use ($team) {
            // Expectation
            $mock->shouldReceive('handle')
                ->with($team)
                ->once();
        }
    );

    // Delete team
    $team->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer for somebody who finds this page like me.
According to [the document](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/events#testing):

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;

Event::fake();

Event::assertListening(
    OrderShippedEvent::class,
    SendShipmentNotificationListener::class
);
```

The second argument also accepts an array of listeners.